# How should I structure a Rakefile with some tasks that need to run during deployment, and others that can't even be defined during deployment?

Tags: rspec, rake, capistrano, bundler, sprockets

I am working with a simple (or so I thought) Sinatra app that uses a few gems during different stages of the application development/deployment cycle:

- Bundler for managing dependencies
- Rake for build tasks
- Sprockets for asset precompilation
- RSpec 2 for tests
- Capistrano for deployment

The Gemfile includes `rspec` in a `test` group.

The Rakefile defines an `assets:compile` task for translating Sass to CSS and CoffeeScript to JavaScript, and concatenating the resulting files.

Capistrano runs `bundle install --without development test` so that only gems needed for production (and asset compilation) are installed on the production server. It also runs a Cap task that ultimately runs `bundle exec rake assets:compile` on the server.

This is all good so far, but I'd like to add the RSpec Rake task to my Rakefile, and that's where things go wrong. It works fine when I run locally, but when I run `cap deploy` I get an error on the server: `no such file to load -- rspec/core/rake_task`.

This makes sense: RSpec isn't installed on the server when we install the bundle, and the spec task will never actually be run there. The error happens just because of trying to define the task.

I can think of a number of options to handle this, but none of them seem quite right to me:

- Wrap `require 'rspec/core/rake_task'` in a `begin...rescue` block and ignore errors
- Take `rspec` out of the `test` group or otherwise force it to be installed on the server
- Use a different rakefile during deployment that only includes the `assets:compile` task
- Define my own `spec` task that only requires RSpec when invoked
- Run the precompile locally rather than on the server (my favorite of these options)

What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, seeing as the Rake does not get invoked on the server very often, I'd keep it simple and use `rescue`:

```
begin
  require 'rspec/core/rake_take'
rescue LoadError
end
```

I'm not sure why with Rails I've never run in to this.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, since I "know" in production that it won't be available and it seems pointless and kludgy to try to search the load path and ignore the failure. This is the solution most people have suggested, however, so I'll go with the crowd! :)

Comment: BTW if you're using rspec-rails with Rails, it defines its own Rake task that will be autoloaded when rspec-rails itself is loaded. So it all "just works" when you put rspec-rails in the test group of your Gemfile.

Comment: So, `rspec-rails` is why I've never had this problem. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by doing

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task' if defined?(RSpec)
```

The reasoning is simplicity. The other solutions would probably suffice as well, but my opinion is that they add more complexity than flexibility. If more cases like this pop up in the future I would considering looking at an alternate solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work, since RSpec will only be defined if I've already required rspec!

Answer (score 0):

I had almost identical issue.

Not sure if this is the 'best practice' but I ended up doing this in Rakefile:

```
if (Rails.env.migration? || Rails.env.production?)
  # define rake tasks that depend on gems installed only in dev/test envs
end
```

(I use a separate environment for migrations that points to the same database as production but has higher database privileges needed to do schema changes.)